# Variant and open generics IReadOnlyList

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to understand why a specific behavior regarding variant and generics in c# does not compile.

```
class Matrix<TLine> where TLine : ILine
{
    TLine[] _lines;

    IReadOnlyList<ILine> Lines { get { return _lines; } } //does not compile
    IReadOnlyList<TLine> Lines { get { return _lines; } } //compile
}
```

I can't understand why this does not work as :

- `_lines`, being of type `TLine[]`, implements `IReadOnlyList<TLine>`
- `IReadOnlyList<out T>` is a variant generic interface, which means, as far as I understand, that anything implementing `IReadOnlyList<TLine>` can be used as a `IReadOnlyList<ILine>`

I feel that it must be because the type constraint is not taken into account, but I doubt it.

Comment: I think you need to add a `class` constraint to `TLine` - `class Matrix<TLine> where TLine : ILine, class`. The covariance of `IReadOnlyList<T>` does not apply if `T` is a value type so you need to restrict `TLine` to be a reference type.

Comment: @Lee I didn't know that either, you should post this as an answer since it solves OPs problem ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add the `class` constraint to `TLine`:

```
class Matrix<TLine> where TLine : class, ILine
```

This will ensure that `TLine` is a reference type - which then allows generic variance to work. Variance *only* works for reference types, because that way the CLR knows that the value of type `TLine` can be used as a value of type `ILine` without any boxing or other change in representation.